# Download public files from SharePoint without credentials using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

How to download Public Shared files from SharePoint without using credentials? I'm trying to download the entire folder.

This is my current script, but its asking for credentials

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

$SiteURL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC"
$LibraryURL= "/Documents/Cloud/All"
$DownloadPath ='C:\Users\John\Desktop\'

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $LibraryURL
```

But **Connect-PnpOnline** asks for credentials, even though its accessibly through browser without creds.

Edit: This is the SP I'm trying to download from [Link](https://captainitriverside.sharepoint.com/sites/ITWorld/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?ga=1&id=%2Fsites%2FITWorld%2FShared%20Documents%2FCloud%2Fautomation&viewid=520a55be%2Da266%2D407e%2Da00e%2D0e4702c53460)

Comment: Are you an admin?  You may need to start PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  An Admin to access files on remote machine needs to replace the colon in the Path with a dollar sign : $DownloadPath ='C$\Users\John\Desktop\'

Comment: You could try `Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -CurrentCredentials` (Use credentials of the currently logged in user)

Comment: @jdweng This isn't on a remote machine. The files are on a folder in SharePoint, and that particular directory (recursive) it shared with public. So, I'm trying to download without logging in SharePoint. Because I'm able to do similarly via browser.

Comment: @Theo That wont work for SharePoint. Basically, I want it to serve are a GitHub Repo, download files without creds even on random PC.

Comment: A sharepoint is a server with its disks shared over the network.  So then network name is \\server_name\c$\path\file or without the drive name  \\server_name$\path\file

Comment: @jdweng I've updated my question with the exact link to SP, I'm unable to use your approach, Can you please elaborate ? Thank you.

Comment: You need credentials.  The link you provided is not reachable without a username and password.   The link uses protocol https and only way of getting files from https is to use FTP (a sub type of http).  There are other protocols to read files files from a network drive like NTFS.  NFTS you would need to have credentials and the network has to allow NTFS to run.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS